# Run a simple script during sleep/suspend

Tags: bash, scripting, suspend, sleep

How can I have a simple bash script run during sleep? The script is pinging a machine on the network every 5 seconds, and if it is online, it will wake the computer from sleep. Is this possible on Ubuntu 18?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: I can't find out how to do it with that link

Comment: who is sleeping, who is awake? how does the awaken know the sleeper is asleep?  how to ping a machine thats offline? And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to execute anything on the OS level while a machine is put to sleep, this would kind defeat the purpose of having it asleep in the first place.